# instance variable is null in show method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, instance

I have developed a rest api, in which I am using instance variable. there are two methods index and show, I have created a instance variable in index method which I want to use in show method on user request.

But i do not know, the instance variable is null in show method, I am sure that I am not initaializing the class anywhere explicitly. Code snippet is below

```
def index
  data = Hash.new

  @temp = DataHelper.filter(params)
  if(params[:type] == 'Student')
    json = DataStudenteHelper.sfilter(params, @temp)
  else
    json = EmpDataHelper.empfilter(params, @temp)
  end
  puts data.to_json
  render :status => :ok, :json => json
end                                                                                          


def show      
  puts @temp.to_json    // null here                                                                                          
  if (params[:type] == 'Student')
    @h = StudentHelpHelper.shfilter(params, @temp)
  else
    @h = EmpDataHelpHelper.emphfilter(params, @temp)
  end
  render :status => :ok, :json => @h
end
```

in the methods sfilter, empfilter, shfilter and emphfilter, I am just processing @temp but it is null in show method...
So any idea what is the issue thanks...

Comment: Why do you expect `@temp` not to be nil? Where do you believe it is being initialized?

Comment: The time I call Datahelper.filter I guess and then using the return value both in index and show.... Is not true

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that a controller will persist across multiple requests so that you can initialize a variable in an `index` action and still be able to use it in a subsequent `show` action. This is not the case. Rails controller instances exist only for the duration of the request they serve. You cannot keep values in memory like this across requests (nor should you want to as that would require that requests be served in a particular order and would leak data between different users).

If you need to initialize this variable before all of your controller actions consider using a before filter. In your case this probably means that you also need to supply the data you need in the params of the show action.

Comment: There's probably a more complete answer possible here but it depends on what these `params` are and how this controller is modeling a resource. Can you describe how these `index` and `show` actions represent a collection of and individual resources?

Comment: These params are the parameters coming from the request from user device such as user_id, email etc. Index action is the main request entry for user and then next one is show that use the data extracted from database which is method Datahelper.filter ... I hope I am clear in your question

Comment: Both of these action seem to render the same response so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here or why you have two actions in the first place. Regardless they need to obtain the data they work with independent of each other.

Comment: Yes true, but in the show action, I want to use same object so that I can save the database retrieval of main query. It is bit similar to pagination  I hope now it is clear....

Comment: Hi, but when I set before action filter, it executes the @temp = DataHelper.filter(params) before both index and show which i do not want...I only wish to executes it before index and use that instance variable in show...

Comment: I understand what you want to do but since a different instance of the controller is created for each request that's not really an option. Consider how else you might handle these actions. Unfortunately I'm not sure what to suggest without a better understanding of why you have two actions which seem to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I want this, because both are different action from device, but connected in the sense that, after reaching first part which is through index then the next part use the queried data from index...both are connected or I can say in clean way that it is like zooming in/out. what do you purpose in this scenerio..any pointer...thanks

Comment: I find it helpful to think about controller actions in terms of the resources they serve. An index action returns a collection of resources. A show action returns a single resource. A "zoom" might identify a single resource in which case a show action which loads only that resource makes sense or it might be expressed as a filter on a collection of resources in which case I would only have an index action and use its parameters to define the zoom range.